# Observium not showing ubuntu icon before my ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, snmp, observium

I just have set up snmpd, observium settings on my ubuntu machine,
but sadly observium webpage shows linux icon before my ubuntu machine's name, 
not the ubuntu logo.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

(machine is mac mini and I installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it)

PS. well, serverfault do net let me, a newbie, attach an image, so I edited this question a little.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I just found that I need to

1. download "distro" script from observium
2. extend the snmpd.conf settings to execute that script to get the distro name
3. restart snmpd

to get the correct OS logo :)